# If $q$ is a square modulo $m$ and modulo $n$, then $q$ is a square modulo $mn$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do I show that if $q,m,n$ are integers, with $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then if $q$ is a square modulo $m$ and modulo $n$, then $q$ is a square modulo $mn$? I am assuming I should use the Chinese remainder theorme but do not know how to start this way?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Assume $q\equiv x^2 \pmod m$ and $q\equiv y^2 \pmod n$. 
Then use the Chinese remainder theorem to get a $z$ such that $z\equiv x\pmod m\ $ and $z\equiv y\pmod n$, and consider $\ z^2-q$.

Comment: Do I start by assuming some z? When employing the Chinese remainder theorem, I got $q \equiv mk_0+x^2 (\mod{mn})$. Where does the z play in?

Comment: As far as I know, the Chinese Remainder Theorem states a one-to-one correspondence between pairs of remainders $(x,y)$, where $x$ is modulo $m$, $y$ is modulo $n$, and remainders $z$ modulo $mn$ if $\gcd(m,n)=1$.